# How to resolve cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python-3.x

After I upgraded to python 3 am getting error cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object.

Below is my code, am getting error on the 2nd line as there is string and byte mismatch.

```
 manually_resync_time =  b'2020-09-07T03:28:55Z chronyd version 3.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)\n2020-09-07T03:28:55Z Could not open IPv6 command socket : Address family not supported by protocol\n2020-09-07T03:28:55Z Frequency -9.450 +/- 0.094 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/drift\n2020-09-07T03:29:28Z System clock wrong by 0.000071 seconds (step)\n2020-09-07T03:29:28Z chronyd exiting\n'

 seconds = re.search( "([0-9]*.[0-9]*) seconds", manually_resync_time).group(0)
 self.assertLess(0.01, seconds)
```

I have tried using struct unpack to convert manually_resync_time  to float

```
struct.unpack('f', manually_resync_time)
```

and now its giving me

> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

How can I resolve this.

Comment: Have you tried just converting `manually_resync_time` to a `str` by using `.decode()` on it?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy  yeah I tried that before and it gave me TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str' for line #3

Comment: `float(seconds)`? Were you trying to compare `0.01` with the string you got from the regex, `'32.53'` or whatever?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) and [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/379906/4518341)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Currently yes, and it worked on py2 but I think instead of converting it to string I'll need a way to have both variables in float type and then the comparison would work, and that why I tried struct.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute, why are you expecting this to work at all? `manually_resync_time` doesn't contain any periods or the word "seconds".

Comment: @wjandrea Sorry, I have updated the question with the correct value

Answer (score 0):

I resolved above by converting manually_resync_time to string using decode function and the seconds to float